# suiteCRM API call returning 401

Tags: python, api, http-status-code-401, suitecrm

i'm trying to call CRM suite api but its just returning 401.

```
{"error":"access_denied","message":"The resource owner or authorization server denied the request.","hint":"Missing \\"Authorization\\" header"}
```

this is how im callling the API in python

```
import requests
url = "https://crm.unlokdevelopment.com/api/access_token"

payload = "{"client_credentials":"client_credentials",\n"client_id":****** ",\n"client_secret":"******"}" print(payload)

headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json', 'Accept': 'application/vnd.api+json' } 

print(headers)
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload) 

print(response)
print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

please tell me what im doing wrong. I have also tried postman but no luck.
i confirmed credentials are correct

Answer (score 0):

Two things I can add

1. Missing the `grant_type` in your request, I use `password` as the type.
2. I had the same problem when NOT using this header `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of the json type.

A full working example in pythong that I got from my insomnia(like postman) saved requests

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("nobody.crm.cr")

payload = "scope=&grant_type=password&client_id=f334234324234234-5e506c358845&client_secret=fiasdasd&username=admin&password=myPasswordIsSecure"

headers = {
    'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'accept': "application/json"
    }

conn.request("POST", "/Api/access_token", payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```